# WMI Network Load Balancing (NLB) - Enumerate multiple ClusterIP Addresses

Tags: c++, windows, wmi, nlb

I have some existing C++ COM code that uses the WMI MicrosoftNLB_Node class to get a single cluster ip address.

I have now added a second IP address to the cluster, and that seems to be working fine (in networking terms).

How can I enumerate all the Cluster IP addresses? None of the WMI NLB objects seem to support an array or other enumerable data item to get the multiple IP addresses.

I have used WMI Explorer to browse the available objects, but can't find one with the required attributes.